# How do I call a ruby function named []?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, so please excuse this question if it is obvious.

I am working with a Module with a function signature that I don't understand.  How would I call this function?

```
module Facter
...
  def self.[](name)
    collection.fact(name)
  end
...
```

In my code I want to reference something that should be in collection.fact, in this Facter module.  What syntax to I use to call this  function?

Cheers

Comment: As an aside, since you are clearly learning ruby, I would suggest a terminological change. Everything in ruby is an object and as such ruby does not have functions, it only has methods (message transmissions).

Answer (score 6):

It works like this:

```
class MyModule
  def self.[](arg)
    puts arg
  end
end

MyModule["Hello world"] # will print Hello world
```

Please see official docs:

https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html

> Additionally, methods for element reference and assignment may be defined: `[]` and `[]=` respectively. Both can take one or more arguments, and element reference can take none.
>
> ```
> class C
>   def [](a, b)
>     puts a + b
>   end
>
>   def []=(a, b, c)
>     puts a * b + c
>   end
> end
>
> obj = C.new
>
> obj[2, 3]     # prints "5"
> obj[2, 3] = 4 # prints "10"
> ```

So about example from docs

```
# From docs
obj[2, 3]

# It's the same as
obj.[](2, 3)
```

More interesting example

```
# From docs
obj[2, 3] = 4
# will print 10
# => 4

# It's the almost as
obj.[]=(2, 3, 4)
# will print 10
# => nil
```

As you see when you call as `obj[2, 3] = 4` Ruby takes the value after `=` as the last argument of the `[]=` method **and return it as method result**

And regardless of whether there is `return` in the method body. For example

```
class C
  def []=(a, b, c)
    puts "Before return"
    return 12
    puts "After return"
  end
end

obj = C.new

obj[2, 3] = 4
# will print Before return
# => 4

obj.[]=(2, 3, 4)
# will print Before return
# => 12
```

It is desirable to define such method with more than one parameter. Technically, you can have only one, but the call will be like this `obj[] = 1`

Comment: It might be helpful to show that both `obj[2,3]` and `obj.[](2,3)` print "5" and both `obj[2, 3] = 4` and `obj.[]=(2,3,4)` print "10".  Consider also having `[]=` make an assignment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `[]=` is not technically assignment in this case. Honestly no method is technically assignment; however, from my understanding, even methods that look like assignment will only be treated like assignment if they meet 2 criteria: 1) contain an equal sign; 2) accept a single argument. Also when I say "treated like assignment" I mean that like true assignment it will always return the argument passed to it, in the same fashion as true assignment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland also note `obj[2, 3] = 4` prints `10` but returns `4` and `obj.[]=(2,3,4)` prints `10` but returns `nil`. `[x]=y` is a special case because technically it accepts 2 arguments however only 1 is on the right side of the equal sign (causing the interpreter to generally "treat" it like assignment) but as you can see from the 2 different calls the `[]=` method is not true assignment and not always interpreted as such. BTW I lost 1 criteria in a comment edit the method must adhere to the rules that govern directly callable method naming e.g. `"2r="` will not be treated like assignment

Comment: It's treated as an assignment when using the assignment _syntax_. The method has no control over this. It doesn't even have to exist to trigger Ruby's assignment behavior (works just fine via `method_missing`).